# Why does std::void_t not work in such a case?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae, type-traits

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename, typename = void>
struct IsIterator final : std::false_type
{};

template<typename T>
struct IsIterator<T,
    std::void_t<std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<std::input_iterator_tag,
        typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category>>>>
    final : std::true_type
{};


int main()
{
    return IsIterator<void*>::value;
}
```

**clang 8.0 gives the following error messages:**

```
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:507:16: error: cannot form a reference to 'void'
    typedef _Tp& reference;
               ^
main.cpp:20:23: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::iterator_traits<void *>' requested
      here
        typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category>>>>
                      ^
main.cpp:29:16: note: during template argument deduction for class template partial specialization
      'IsIterator<T, std::void_t<std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<std::input_iterator_tag, typename
      std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category> > > >' [with T = void *]
        return IsIterator<void*>::value;
               ^
main.cpp:29:16: note: in instantiation of template class 'IsIterator<void *, void>' requested here
```

**Why does `std::void_t` not work in such a case?**

Comment: Notice that `std::void_t` is redundant with `std::enable_if_t` which already returns `void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category` forces instantiation of `std::iterator_traits<T>` which is ill formed (hard error and not soft error for SFINAE) for `void*`.

You have to handle `void*` manually.